# Code inside <pre> tags need not be indented

Tags: bug, code-formatting

It's asking me to indent the code even though it's inside `<pre>` tag

[What is this \u001b[9... syntax of choosing what color text appears on console, and how can I add more colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975735/what-is-this-u001b9-syntax-of-choosing-what-color-text-appears-on-console)

resulting in horribly double spaced code

Comment: Why use `<pre>` at all.  Markup should take care of virtually any code properly with the added HTML

Comment: Solution: *don't use `<pre>`.* I edited your post for you.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters, I was using `<pre>` to achieve what could be achieved with `<!-- -->`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because the Markdown parser doesn't really understand physical HTML inside your post. It *allows* it, but *assumes* you are using it properly and does not try to verify the fact.

You have two line breaks after your `<pre>` tags, which is causing the parser to think the `<pre>` tag itself is a paragraph of text, and then you have code that is not indented to be shown as code.

Ultimately, you should just avoid using the `<pre>` element and use the Markdown-equivalent.

Comment: Could you show the markdown proper way to get pre formatted text *without* any syntax highlighting in it?

Comment: @MichaelT You can always use `<!-- language: none -->`. Or if you really want to use `<pre>`, just make sure you start the content immediately after the tag, no line breaks.